# Foreign relations are not generated while reverse engineering in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, reverse-engineering, database-schema, pojo

I tried to reverse engineer the POJOs from Database Schema using hibernate. While the classes and their DAO generated properly, I found that the relations between classes were not generated.

For ex, **Friend** table has reference to **User** table but the **Friend** table only contains the ids and not the actual **User** object.

I tried to find out the cause of it, but couldnt. One weird thing that i found was the .reveng.xml file did not contain any property values, if that is weird.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both **Friend** and **User** table in .reveng.xml file

```
<table-filter match-name="Friend" />
<table-filter match-name="User" />
```

I think this will resolve your problem.